# Angular [required] not working, conditional requirement

Tags: angular, required

```
[required]="ItemCode !== 'This' || ItemCode !== 'That'”
```

Hello, just want to check whether this line of code is correct as it doesn’t seem to work! Sorry if this is kinda a simple question to ask but I’m new to coding and can’t seem to find the answer best for my needs! Thank you all in advance.

I’m trying to make the barcode a conditional requirement when select “this” or “that” in the dropdown lost the barcode will not be required.

Comment: you need to write `[attr.required]="your conditions"`

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? If it's not working, then it probably isn't correct, but unless you can tell us what you want to happen, and what is happening instead, I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: This can be achieved via rxweb conditional validation https://rxweb.io/form-validations/required/validators

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I  indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you need to write `[attr.required]="your conditions"`, all native HTML elements attribute you can use like this way.